# is it possible to return response from fetch with just promise (no async/await)

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

Why this doesn't work (I borrowed to https://jsfiddle.net/xlanglat/tyh6jjpy/):

```
  callWs2 = function(){
    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
  }

  console.log(callWs2());
```

Comment: You need a `return` for `callWs2`. The callback in the `.then()` won't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.then` method returns a `Promise` and in your case it returns a `Promise` that resolves with whatever `response.text()` resolves with. Note: `response.text()` also returns a `Promise`.

> Returns another pending promise object, the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by then will be subsequent to the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the resolved value of the promise returned by then will be the same as the resolved value of the promise returned by the handler. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value).

Now, you need to `return` this `Promise` from your function.

And finally when you're calling the function you need to chain it with `.then` because the function returns a `Promise`.

```js
function callWs2() {
  let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      const res = response.text();
      console.log(res instanceof Promise); // true
      return res;
    })
}

callWs2().then(console.log);
```

Comment: so you cannot stop a promise and just get a value ?